# Can I wire a security camera into a switched lighting circuit?

Tags: camera, lighting

I live in a building with a communal stairway. This has lights which are switched on each floor, controlled by a timer box which holds the lights on for 2 minutes after the push button is pressed.

I want to install a Raspberry pi zero running Motion Eye to act as a security camera.

The only power available is from the lighting circuit. I’ve opened a nearby connector box and have 3 wires: N, L and Switched L. What I observe is that I have 240VAC between L-N when the lights are off. This drops to 5VAC when the lights are on so is insufficient to power the PSU for the pi. The Switched L is of course 0VAC when off and 240VAC when on.

I’ve observed that there is a 100VAC voltage between L and SL when the lights are on, rising to 240VAC when they are off.

So, my question is, is it acceptable to connect a Raspberry pi PSU across L and SL?

Comment: It's only acceptable for a qualified electrician to do this.

Comment: If the voltage between L and N drops to 5 when the lights are on, at least one of those wires isn't what you think it is.

Comment: And following what @Finbarr said, is this a three-way connection? Is there one and only one switch for the lights? Find a way of powering a single 5V PSU from the eletric light circuit in a hallway is somewhat a trivial task for a qualified person, **but**, if you need to ask general advice about how you would do it, you definitely should not be dealing with this kind of task.

Comment: If you are not an electrician, and don't have a permit from building managenent, you are not allowed to install it for many reasons (you could be stealing electricity and monitoring public areas illegally).

Comment: The answer is no. You always have to pick the power from L and N, else you won't have the right voltage. In this case you can turn on your security device only when the lights are on.

Comment: ...and a pi won't like having its power turned on and off regularly.  Even apart from the safety/permission issues, this while idea is a non-starter.

Answer (score -2):

Since your Raspberry needs 5v DC, you'll require an ac adapter with a wide input range whose output is 5v DC and 2A. There're tons of them out there, you only need to search.